# Multiple vertical-align properties same line CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Was looking at the `vertical-align`  property of `CSS`. I have used it quite a bit and normally you can use it like this:

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

#text {
  background-color: powderblue;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Texttext <span id="text">Texttext</span>Texttext
</div>
```

However, what I don't understand is that if  the `vertical-align` is changed this can influence the position of the other inline elements (other text in this case)

For example if we change the `vertical-align` from 30px to -30px:

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

#text {
  background-color: powderblue;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Texttext <span id="text">Texttext</span>Texttext
</div>
```

The results is that text outside the span (with no `vertical-align` property) is completely changed from position.

### Questions

1. Why does vertical align also affects other elements besides the element where the property is put on?
2. Is this anyhow related to line-height? Can line-height change the behaviour of the `vertical-align` property?

Comment: When I tested it, I did not have any problem with vertical-align. It only moved the #text down as expected and did not affect other elements. Can you try again to run it again?

Comment: But in the first example I provided why is the span pushing the other elements down?

Comment: It's my bad. I did not see your first example. It is normal to vertical-align. You can see some example here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=baseline.

Comment: If it does not do so, there are no space to move the #text up. If you don't like that behaviour, you can use position: absolute or relative to move your #text up or down

Comment: I got it now, was looking from the wrong perspective to it. Thanks!